# Why aren't my virtual hosts on WampServer working?

Tags: apache, virtual, hosts

I am having difficulty hosting two websites at the same time on WampServer. Here is what I have done already:

My source files for my websites are respectively C:\wamp\www\familyhistorywebsitetemplate and C:\wamp\www\cutillowebdesign

1. I edited the host file by adding the below to the end of the file (not on the same line and without the semicolon:)

127.0.0.1       cutillohistory.tk;
127.0.0.1       familyhistorywebsites.tk

2: I uncommented "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" in the httpd.conf file to enable my virtual hosts in Apache

3: I set up the virtual host in WAMP (C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf) - this is what it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin localhost.admin
Document Root  "C:\wamp\www"
ServerName localhost
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@cutillohistory.tk
DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\cutillowebdesign"
ServerName cutillohistory.tk
ServerAlias www.cutillohistory.tk
<Directory "C:\wamp\www\cutillowebdesign">
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/cutillohistory.tk-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/cutillohistory.tk-access.log" common
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@familyhistorywebsites.tk
DocumentRoot "C:\Websites\familyhistorywebsitetemplate"
DirectoryIndex index.cfm index.php
ServerName familyhistorywebsites.tk
ServerAlias www.familyhistorywebsites.tk
<Directory "C:\Websites\familyhistorywebsitetemplate">
   AllowOverride All 
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "logs/familyhistorywebsites.tk-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/familyhistorywebsites.tk-access.log" common
```

Any help you can give me is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see either of the VirtualHost closing tags (`</VirtualHost>`).  Copy/paste error, or have you forgotten them?

Comment: My apologies I just noticed that - it was just a copy and paste error, I DO have the VirtualHost closing tags